# Serilog implementation broke Options pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, serilog

I am using Azure functions (In-process). I had implementation of options pattern.
The options pattern does not work after I had installed packages Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights. That means it is not possible to get any value from config file in service consructor.

Startup:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
        var context = builder.GetContext();
        var config = context.Configuration;
        builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(config);
        builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        
         //only this was added
        builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
}
```

MyConfig:

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

MyService:

```
public class MyService
{
        private readonly MyConfig _config;
        private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;

        public MyService(IOptions<MyConfig> config, ILogger<MyService> logger)
        {
            _config = config.Value; 
            //config.Value.MyProp = null
            _logger= logger; 
        }
}
```

Update: It does not register IOptions.

Comment: what was the error you were getting? and also, tell me the exact requirement.

Comment: I got no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it. In the startup the configure should be:

> builder.Services.Configure(config.Bind);

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the options pattern using `builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(config)`, it read from the `config` object and registered with the dependency injection container.

- Adding of Serilog logging with Application Insights might be interfering with the options binding process. So, try to add before configuring the options pattern.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(YourNamespace.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp11
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var context = builder.GetContext();
            var config = context.Configuration;

            // Register IOptions for MyConfig
            builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(config);

            // Add logging first
            builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));

            builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyConfig _config;
    private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;

    public MyService(IOptions<MyConfig> config, ILogger<MyService> logger)
    {
        _config = config.Value;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (_config.MyProp == "48397")
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MyConfig MyProp Value is 48397");
        }
    }
}
```

- Install NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`
- When I call the `DoSomething` method in Azure Function, it will log the message "MyConfig MyProp Value is 48397" using Serilog. The log message will appear in Application Insights as below.

**Test result:**

[image]